# Node js, starting Discord.js bot using exec, doesn’t properly run

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So let’s say I have 2 files, a.js and b.js, where a.js is a simple node.js script which calls b.js which is a Discord.js bot.

**a.js**

```
const { exec } = require(‘child_process’);
exec(‘node b.js’, (err,stdout,stderr) => {
console.log(‘err: ‘ + err + ‘\n stdout: ‘ + stdout + ‘\n stderr:‘ + stderr);
});
```

**b.js**

```
const Discord = require(‘discord.js’);
const fs = require(‘fs’);
var bot = new Discord.Client();
var token;
fs.readFile(‘token.txt’,(err,data) => {
    if(err){console.log(err); process.exit(0);}
    token = data;
});
bot.on(‘ready’,()=>{console.log(‘ready’);});
bot.on(‘message’, message => {
    if(message.content == ‘ping’){
        message.channel.send(‘pong’);
    }
});
bot.login(token);
```

When I run a.js, the only output is

```
err:
stdout:
stderr:
```

a.js then terminates and it appears as if b.js never ran.
I was wondering why this happens and why.
Additionally if anyone is wondering why I am doing this, I have this as apart of a bigger script and I boiled down the problem to this. And the main part is that b.js MUST be run from exec. I am running this in Windows 10 using the most recent version of node, and Discord.js. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another go at this but when through the full discord bot setup...

my `a.js` looks like this...

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const child = spawn('node',['b.js']);

process.stdin.pipe(child.stdin);

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`child stdout:\n${data}`);
});

child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`child stderr:\n${data}`);
});
```

My `b.js` looks like this...

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
var bot = new Discord.Client();
var token;
fs.readFile('token.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'}, (err,token) => {
    if(err){console.log(err); process.exit(0);}

    bot.on('ready',()=>{
            console.log('ready');
    });
    bot.on('message', message => {
        if(message.content == 'ping'){
            message.channel.send('pong');
        }
    });

    bot.login(token);
});
```

On `b.js`, I had to `utf8` the file read, and make sure my `token.txt` file had no trailing, leading white space. Also, i moved the bot login code into the callback of the token file read.

Output example below...

[image]

I sent ping through on discord to see if it works, and the bot responded with pong.

Screenshot below.
[image]

I hope this code works for you, let me know...

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at running a.js with b.js, except I changed b.js to simply console.log

a.js

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('node b.js', (err,stdout,stderr) => {
console.log('err: ' + err + '\n stdout: ' + stdout + '\n stderr:' + stderr);
});
```

b.js

```
console.log("B was called");
```

Then when i run node a.js i get;

```
node .\a.js
err: null
 stdout: B was called

 stderr:
```

I'm guessing there's a path issue where A can't find B relative to where it's being called from?

Comment: That isn’t the issue I’m having, because when I do what you did, it works fine

Comment: No worries, i've posted another answer below, hope it helps :)